# Drying up rails models code into concerns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I've got 2 scopes that I can reuse across 3 different models, now I have same scope test in all of the models, so I thought of doing something like having a shared test :

```
RSpec.shared_examples 'build_info' do |clazz|
  describe 'scopes' do
    context 'buildable' do
        it '0 builds' do
          expect(clazz.builds.count(:all)).to eq(0)
        end

         it '3 builds' do
          expect(clazz.builds(:even).count(:all)).to eq(3)
        end
    end
  end
end
```

Then in one of `MyModel` spec this portion :

```
describe MyModel do
  include MyModule
  RSpec.include_example 'build_info', MyModel

  #relevant test
  describe 'scopes' do
    it_behaves_like 'build_info'
  end
end
```

I get this error now :

```
my_model_spec.rb:5:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `include_example' for RSpec:Module (NoMethodError)
```

What am I doing wrong?

This is the error when I remove the `RSpec` prefix from the `include_example` :

```
gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:656:in 
`method_missing': undefined method `include_example' for 

RSpec::ExampleGroups::MyModel:Class (NoMethodError)
```

This is my rspec info from the Gemfile.lock :

```
rspec-collection_matchers (1.1.2)
      rspec-expectations (>= 2.99.0.beta1)
    rspec-core (3.3.2)
      rspec-support (~> 3.3.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.3.1)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.3.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.3.2)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.3.0)
    rspec-rails (3.3.3)
      actionpack (>= 3.0, < 4.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0, < 4.3)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 4.3)
      rspec-core (~> 3.3.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.3.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.3.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.3.0)
    rspec-support (3.3.0)
```

Why am I getting `undefined method`include_example'`, do I need to include something in my **test config** or **file**?

Comment: "now I have same scope test in all of the models" - why do you need to test the same code multiple times? If the scopes are in a module you include in the models, just test them separately.

Comment: @aledalgrande I am testing them separately, I want to make sure the code is actually working in all models, because they include separate modules and are not the same, so it's possible that it's working on one model and not on another. And why have the same code 3 time is the question, once should be enough